# What is this Oracle SQL Syntax ${}?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle query which has a select statement

```
select table.columnname = ${sometext_sometext_sometext}
```

I would like to know what is the purpose of `${}`. 
Also this throws an error in Oracle SQL developer. Kindly advise what is the work around.

Comment: Show this `some text_some text` actual value. Probably some kind of template for IDE

Comment: The statement shown is not a valid Oracle SELECT statement, irregardless of the ${} stuff. That might work in MySQL or PostgreSQL, though...

Comment: @BobJarvis: it's definitely invalid in Postgres.

Comment: `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh` and other shells allow variable names to be surrounded in `{}` chars, i.e. `${my_var}`. I think that is what you're seeing. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't Oracle syntax, this is a common syntax for interpolating variables into a string found in Perl, Groovy, and a bunch of other languages.

You don't say what the context is here, but what is probably going on is something modifies the file, probably with environment-related properties, before the SQL gets run, the `${}` is there to identify to the modifying script what value to substitute here. This is a common thing to do when you have environment-specific properties that need to be injected into a SQL script.

Comment: is there a sample code for this? wanted to see how this looks like

Answer (score 0):

Can you give some background as to where you got this SQL statement? It appears that you are working with a query that requires pre-processing via Java, PHP, a Bash shell script, etc. Standard Oracle SQL or PL/SQL does not know what to do with the "${}" syntax.

I have used this syntax in a standard SQL template that I then process in Java or a bash shell script to generate the final SQL statement.